# VueJs component names

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm working in VueJS and i have the following code

```
<li @click = "selectedComponent = 'appManagment'"><i class="ion-clipboard"></i>Management</li>
```

so what i try to accomplish is to display the name like `{{selectedComponent}}`

but as excpected it displays "appManagment" because this is the component that was selected.
So the question is, how to display a different name, for example i want just "Managment" to appear instead of "appManagment".
I'm using it for the navigation menu that displays where the user is located, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: as much as I would like to help you I think i don't understand your problem

Comment: is it possible to make "selectedComponents" display a different name? like its displaying appManagment -> is the right component i need but i just want a more beautiful name to display (in my navigation), how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I would create an object like the one below

```
var prettyNames = {
    'appManagment': 'Some very nice name'
}
```

and then just use it whenever you want to display text which corresponds to the currently selected component. For example

```
prettyNames[selectedComponent]
```

Comment: thank you very much man, i knew it would be very basic solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can register a custom filter with the global Vue.filter() method, passing in a filterID and a filter function. The filter function takes a value as the argument and returns the transformed value:

```
Vue.filter('custom', function (value) { 
   // add your code to determine 
   // name based on value here

   return newName;
 })
```

Then use your filter on the text:

```
<i class="ion-clipboard"></i>{{ selectedComponent | custom }}
```